# Webform checkboxes validation

Tags: webforms

Using Drupal 8, we've built a webform using the Webform module. This form uses the checkboxes element (6 in total) of which we've set to required which to my understanding means at least one checkbox needs to be checked in order for it to pass validation.

During testing, we're noticing that the validation message is not being displayed when the checkboxes are left unchecked.

Is this a bug with the Webform module or is it an ID10T error on my part?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-D At the first sight it indeed looks like a bug which then should be reported in Webform's issue queue not here, including the exported config of that form. But I don't know what an ID10T error on your site is supposed to mean. And did you already try to fill the form as a non-admin user? Maybe you can edit your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: Hi leymannx and thank you for the kind reception! So it appears that the validation IS working, but the "required" message is NOT being displayed. Interestingly enough, when I testing the form, then switching back to building the form, the "required" message IS displayed. Weird right? I did test the form without being logged into the site and it still doesn't display the "required" error message when no check boxes are checked. The ID10T error is me being an idiot and not being able to figure this out without bothering other folks for help.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe adding some custom Javascript within the CSS/JS section would be the right approach.

Comment: It is very likely that your theme is not displaying the error messages. If you switch to the Bartik theme, do you see the error messages?

Comment: The theme was indeed causing the error message from being displayed. To get around this issue we wound up writing a custom JavaScript function that handled the validation and it works well. Thanks for the feedback!